# Why is there a high minimum current required for a clamp meter to measure frequency in addition to current?

Tags: current-measurement, frequency-measurement

Modern clamp meters use hall effect sensors to measure AC and DC current and normally calculate True-RMS. But for the meter to display the frequency of the measured current some require significant current to be flowing.

For example for the Fieldpiece SC680

> Frequency (Hz) Through Clamp
>
> Minimum current range: >7AAC (10 to 100Hz); >20AAC (100 to 400Hz) on
> 100AAC range; >25AAC (10 to 400Hz) on 600AAC range.

Why is this?